# how to crawling arxiv sanity?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want crawling "link", "title" and "abstract"

how can I get crawling this?

I tried

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/top?timefilter=year&vfilter=all'
res = requests.get(url)
text = res.text
# print(text)

d = json.loads(text)
print(d['title'], d['link'], d['abstract'])
```

but `SONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` occur

Comment: Have you verified that the contents of `text` is JSON?

Comment: Can you use BeautifulSoup, for example?

Comment: in BeautifulSoup res is view-source:http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/top?timefilter=year&vfilter=all then how can I extract just title, link, abstract?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/top?timefilter=year&vfilter=all'
res = requests.get(url)
text = res.text
soup=bs(text, "html.parser")
extract=soup.select('script')[6]

target = extract.decode().split('var papers = ')[1]
target2 = target.replace("}, {","}xxx{").replace('[{','{').replace('}];','}')
final = target2.split('xxx')

for i in range(len(final)):
    if i == len(final)-1:
        last = final[i].split('var pid')[0]
        d = json.loads(last)        
        print(d['title'],d['link'],d['abstract'])
    else:
        d = json.loads(final[i])
        print(d['title'],d['link'],d['abstract'])
```

Sample output:

```
BERT: Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language       Understanding 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805v2 
We introduce a new language representation model called BERT, which stands
for Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers. Unlike recent
language representation models, BERT is designed to pre-train deep
bidirectional representations from unlabeled text by jointly conditioning on
both left and right context in all layers...
```

etc.

Comment: it's amazing!. Excellent. Thank you very much.

But can you crawl into one line without a newline in an abstract? replact '\\n' to ' '

Comment: @gilj - What exactly do you mean by "crawl into one line without a newline"? Can you show an example?

Comment: in final variable has "abstract": "We introduce a new language representation model called BERT, which stands\\nfor like this  I want replace '\\n' to ' '

Comment: Oh i did target2 = target.replace("}, {","}xxx{").replace('[{','{').replace('}];','}').replace('\\n', ' ') is done Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

That URL returns an HTML, not a json response. So you can't JSON decode it.

Comment: how can extract title, link, abstract using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

`arxiv-sanity` response seems to have changed. Here is updated version of [jack-fleeting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9448090/jack-fleeting)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313430/15206559).

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/top?timefilter=year&vfilter=all'
res = requests.get(url)
text = res.text
soup=bs(text, "html.parser")
extract=soup.select('script')[6]

extract = soup.select('script')[1]
target = extract.decode().split('var papers = ')[1]

target2 = target.replace("}, {","}xxx{").replace('[{','{').replace('}];','}')
final = target2.split('xxx')

for i in range(len(final)):
        # try:
        if i == len(final)-1:
            last = final[i].split('var tags')[0]
            
            d = json.loads(last)        
            
            # It doesn't give 'abstract', 'link' anymore
            # print(d['title'],d['link'],d['abstract'])
            
            # Instead, it gives 'id' which can be used to make linkq
            link = "https://arxiv.org/abs/" + d['id']

            print(d['title'], link ,d['summary'])
            
    
        else:
            d = json.loads(final[i])
            
            # It doesn't give 'abstract', 'link' anymore
            # print(d['title'],d['link'],d['abstract'])
            
            # Instead, it gives 'id' which can be used to make linkq
            link = "https://arxiv.org/abs/" + d['id']

            print(d['title'], link ,d['summary'])
```